# When doing a manual sign_in for the user in Devise, how can you set remember me to yes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise), I'm signing in my user like this:

```
sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
```

In the default sign in page, there's a checkbox that the user can select so that they don't have to sign in again when they return to the site. But when you do the sign in with the `sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)` line, I can't work out how to set that parameter to yes. Does anyone know how? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
current_user.remember_me!
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb#L54

Note that this only updates the `remember_created_at` value of the user record. But for this to work correctly, a validation token also needs to be stored in the Devise cookie. To achieve both these things, follow Dmytrii's advise and user the `remember_me <USER>` controller method instead:

```
include Devise::Controllers::Rememberable
...
remember_me <USER_OBJECT>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Instead I had to use https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/rememberable.rb `include Devise::Controllers:Rememberable` and then in the action just call `remember_me the_user`

Comment: I also had to do what Dmytrii suggested (although it's include Devise::Controllers::Rememberable (missing the other colon before Rememberable))

Answer (score 6):

Did some testing. Presenting the findings for others.

The simplest solution, assuming the user object has the rememberable module defined on the `devise` declarable, is to set remember_me to true on the user before sign in and redirect:

```
@user.remember_me = true
sign_in_and_redirect(@user, :event => :authentication)
```