# Devise: how can I manually set a remember_user_token cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, session-cookies

I'm using devise 1.1.RC0 for user authentication in a rails 3.0.0 app.

Due to a problem with this version of devise, and the fact that our login process takes place on a (secure) subdomain, when a user logs in, the `remember_user_token` cookie does not get set. This only happens in production where subdomains are involved: the app will correctly set a `remember_user_token` cookie when testing locally.

To get around this problem, I've adjusted my `user_sessions#create` action to set this `remember_user_token` manually:

```
  def create
    user = User.where("lower(email) = ?", params[:user][:email].downcase).first
    if user and user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      sign_in(:user, user)
      current_user.remember_me = true if params[:user][:remember_me]

      #ensure remember_user_token is set
      if Rails.env.production?
        cookies.signed["remember_user_token"] = {
          :value => user.class.serialize_into_cookie(user),
          :expires => 3.months.from_now,
          :domain => ".app_name.com",
        }
      end

    else
      flash[:error] = "Login incorrect"
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

This does set a `remember_user_token` cookie in production. From there, if I delete the session cookie using browser tools and then refresh the page, the session cookie pops back in and I remain logged in - which I assume is what the `remember_user_token` cookie is responsible for.

However, if I close the browser and restart my computer while logged in, I'm no longer logged in when I turn my computer back on and go to my app's url.

**What's the correct way to set this `remember_user_token` cookie?** What I'm I missing? I'd appreciate any help.

Here's my `session_store` initializer:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_app_name_session', :domain => '.appname.com'
else
  AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_app_name_session'
end
```

Here's the relevant code in my `User` model:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to reload the user before passing them to serialize_into_cookie:

```
  sign_in(:user, user)
  current_user.remember_me!

  #ensure remember_user_token is set
  if Rails.env.production?
    cookies.signed["remember_user_token"] = {
      :value => user.class.serialize_into_cookie(user.reload),
      :expires => 3.months.from_now,
      :domain => ".app_name.com",
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

### Simple Way

```
@user.remember_me = true
sign_in(@user)
```

---

*<sup>Source: [When doing a manual sign_in for the user in Devise, how can you set remember_me to yes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18434995/1533054)</sup>*

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual code I ended up with:

```
def set_current_user(user, remember_me: false)
  sign_out(:user)
  sign_in(:user, user)

  if remember_me
    user.remember_me!
    cookies.signed[:remember_user_token] = {
      value: user.class.serialize_into_cookie(user.reload),
      expires: user.class.remember_for.from_now
    }
  end
end
```